# AWS Glue Trigger stuck in Deactivating state

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, aws-glue

I have a trigger in AWS glue that is stuck the DEACTIVATING state.  When in the state, you cannot enable it.  I have tried deleting (both in the console and cli) but get the following error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the DeleteTrigger operation: The operation is not allowed when trigger is in state: DEACTIVATING
```

Has anyone come across this before?  Is there a way to force delete?  I cannot see anything in the documentation.

Comment: Open a support request with AWS and ask them to delete it / investigate.

Comment: Thanks Luk2302 that indeed was the only option, and even then it took 3 weeks to resolve while they were looking for the root cause.